# How can I generate a HTML with table tags from PDF?

Tags: python, pdf

I have some PDF files which I would like to convert to HTML. There are some tools which support this, but tables are simply absolute positioned `<span>` tags. They don't produce `<table>` tags.

How can I get table tags?

Here is an [example PDF file](https://github.com/MartinThoma/algorithms/blob/master/PDF/PDF-export-example.pdf). I would hope to get something like this:

```html
<h1>Test document</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed pulvinar nisi quis mauris egestas, maximus
congue tellus tempor. Quisque semper augue consectetur mattis imperdiet. Aliquam elementum, nibh
id scelerisque malesuada, arcu mauris ultricies tellus, non ultrices nulla lacus non erat. Curabitur in
diam a magna ornare finibus. Sed dapibus ipsum laoreet justo eleifend commodo. Nulla porttitor eros
odio, nec cursus mi sagittis eu. Duis metus arcu, auctor gravida interdum sed, congue a velit. Aliquam
malesuada posuere erat sit amet vehicula. Nunc vitae tempus orci. Nulla a elementum magna, vitae
scelerisque nisl. Phasellus gravida elit eu hendrerit tristique. Etiam rutrum ac ipsum vitae consequat.
Nam sit amet gravida arcu. Sed eget dictum lorem, eu consectetur sapien.</p>

<p>Donec gravida, velit ac vehicula feugiat, sem lectus hendrerit purus, non fermentum tortor neque id
tortor. Fusce iaculis feugiat tincidunt. Etiam nec metus leo. Nunc faucibus ut nisi vitae viverra. Aenean
quam lorem, maximus non odio quis, laoreet porttitor nunc. Duis sed viverra magna. Maecenas ut
ipsum eu erat pulvinar aliquet. Cras sed quam nec lectus sollicitudin venenatis vel vitae velit. Nullam
dignissim orci tempus, ultricies dui eget, placerat sem. Phasellus facilisis, felis eget laoreet aliquam, nisi
arcu vehicula orci, sed viverra velit nunc vel ipsum. Etiam in ligula fringilla, interdum massa nec,
elementum est.</p>

<h2>A small section</h2>
<p>Quisque tincidunt tempus lorem eu faucibus. Etiam vitae ¥ maximus diam. Cras ac augue a erat
elementum gravida. Aenean erät $ metus, maximus sit amet dapibus eü €, vulpötate vel arcu £.
Maecenas non vulputate mauris. Phasellus at purus et sapien mattis fringilla. Sed facilisis velit a elit
volutpat fringilla. Curabitur dapibuß urna eu ligula finibus egestas ac eget eros. Vestibulum ante
ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Etiam in urna placerat, convallis
diam in, dignissim mauris. Phasellus ornare laoreet dui id aliquam. Praesent vitae lacus urna. Mauris
urna libero, egestas vel eros ac, tempus suscipit odio. Cras non varius ipsum. Ut vestibulum orci ut
nisl ornare maximus. Nulla condimentum condimentum risus at varius</p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <th>Q1/2011</th>
        <th>Q1/2012</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Earnings per share</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ordinary share</td>
        <th>0.65 €</th>
        <th>0.85 €</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Preferered Share</td>
        <th>0.66 €</th>
        <th>0.86 €</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Portfolio companies Revenue</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>In million €</td>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Abarax IV</td>
        <th>12<sup>1</sup></th>
        <th>34</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Beryol VIII</td>
        <th>56</th>
        <th>78</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cetra EUR II</td>
        <th>90</th>
        <th>-</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### What I tried

#### pymupdf

```py
import fitz

def to_html(filepath: str):
    doc = fitz.open(filepath)
    for i, page in enumerate(doc):
        text = page.getText("html")
        with open(f"pymupdf-page-{i}.html", "w") as fp:
            fp.write(text)
    doc.close()
```

#### Camelot

Camelot can extract the table as a dataframe, but it fails to understand that the rest is not a table.

#### pdftohtml

`pdftohtml -c` gives me the same output as pymupdf - no semantic tables.

Comment: Are you looking for reflowable HTML? Or fixed layout HTML? What about images and vector path content, do you want that exported to HTML? Or just the text and tables?

Comment: Good questions, @Ryan! I'm not sure, but I think I prefer reflowable HTML. Raster and vector images should also be exported to HTML if possible. If not possible, I don't care too much. (Is "vector path content" the same as "vector images"?)

Comment: Are you looking for gratis, open source (FOSS) only? Or are you open to commercial products?

Comment: I'm open to anything :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The company I work for has been offering a PDF table to reflowable HTML extraction tool for years.

https://www.pdftron.com/document-understanding/

There is an online demo here where you can try out your PDF files.

https://www.pdftron.com/pdf-tools/pdf-table-extraction/

New updates to the SDK and demo are coming regularly.